# I cannot share my Observable stream properly and my http request calls twice

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

Hey I have a problem with share operator. When I use async pipe with data$ and totalElements$ my http request executes twice. I wish it would execute only once. I tried to use shareReplay istead and It did not work as well.

```
filters$: BehaviorSubject<any> = ...
...

getComplaints() {
  return this.filters$.pipe(
    flatMap(filters => {
      this.loading = true;
      return this.complaintService
        .getComplaints$(filters)
        .pipe(
          finalize(() => this.loading = false),
          share()
        );
      })
    );
 }

this.data$ = this.getComplaints().pipe(map(value => value.pageItems));
this.totalElements$ = this.getComplaints().pipe(map(value => value.totalItems));
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `shareReplay(1)` before `flatMap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `share` to work you have to create only one observable (so don't use a function) and put the operator on the outer observable. You'll probably want to use `shareReplay` so that late subscribers get the latest value.

```ts
this.complaints$ = this.filters$.pipe(
  flatMap(filters => {
    this.loading = true;
    return this.complaintService
      .getComplaints$(filters)
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => this.loading = false),
      );
    }),
  shareReplay(1)
);

this.data$ = this.complaints$.pipe(map(value => value.pageItems));
this.totalElements$ = this.complaints$.pipe(map(value => value.totalItems));
```

Comment: 2 additions: `this.loading = true`should be moved to a tap. The `finalize` part should also be moved to the outer stream.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm `finalize` on the outer stream wouldn't make much sense as the outer stream (this.filters$) is not intended to complete. Only the inner http request completes.

Comment: You are right, but maybe a second tap is the better choice then.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I also tried to use tap to set loading as false in outer observable it works as well. In fact finalize used with inner Observable works fine.